# How to get top row by date and Id TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this:

[image]

I can't figure out how I can get rows based on `DomainId` and highest date.

I want to get 3 rows, one for each unique domainId and it has to be the highest date for that `domainId`

One of my many attempts:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DomainId, DomainName, 
    Max([Date]), ServerOnline, DatabaseOnline, ServerPerformance, 
    DatabasePerformance, SoldTickets
FROM
    DomainDetailDataHistory
GROUP BY 
    DomainId, DomainName, ServerOnline, DatabaseOnline, 
    ServerPerformance, DatabasePerformance, SoldTickets
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have everything in the output table in your `GROUP BY` statement, so it will return a new row for each unique combination of values in the respective columns.

Try putting the `DomainId` and `MAX([Date])` associated into a Temp Table first, then `INNER JOIN` the table on `DomainId` and `[Date]`.

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @Latest TABLE
(
    DomainId bigint, 
    [date] datetime2
)

INSERT INTO @Latest (DomainId, date)
SELECT DomainId, MAX(Date)
FROm DomainDetailDataHistory
GROUP BY DomainId


SELECT DISTINCT H.DomainId, DomainName,H.[Date],ServerOnline,DatabaseOnline, ServerPerformance, DatabasePerformance, SoldTickets
FROM DomainDetailDataHistory H
INNER JOIN @Latest T ON T.DomainId = H.DomainId AND T.[Date] = H.[Date]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have dual tags - this is for SQL Server:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT DomainId, DomainName, [Date], serverOnline, DatabaseOnline, 
              ServerPerformance, DatabasePerformance, SoldTickets,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DomainId ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
         FROM DomainDetailDataHistory 
     ) AS tt
WHERE tt.rn = 1
```

Comment: This was new to me, never used "over" before. thank you for your answer, If it is not to much to ask do ou have a guide/tutorial for the "over" function?

Comment: search msdn for row_number()

Answer (score 1):

This will also work but only if you are working with **SQL Server 2012+**.

```
;WITH DomainDetailHistoryMax AS 
(
 SELECT 
 DomainId, DomainName, [Date], serverOnline, DatabaseOnline, 
          ServerPerformance, DatabasePerformance, SoldTickets
 ,LEAD([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY DomainID ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS cnt
 )
 SELECT 
 DomainId, DomainName, [Date], serverOnline, DatabaseOnline, 
          ServerPerformance, DatabasePerformance, SoldTickets
 FROM DomainDetailHistoryMax 
 WHERE cnt IS NULL;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx